# Could not start pdflatex

Tags: texlive, texstudio

I hate to ask similar question to many that had been asked here before but none of the responses helped me solve my problem so I'm quite defeated at the moment.

The problem I'm having is with TeXstudio (4.2.3) installed in Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS. Whenever I try to compile a document with pdflatex I get this error `Error: Could not start the command: pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode <file name>.tex` even though if I attempt to run the same command on the same file from the terminal (even within texstudio itself) it works just as expected.

Running `pdflatex --version` in the terminal returns `pdfTeX 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.24 (TeX Live 2022)` and it is included in PATH. Also, `tlmgr --version` returns correct data as well, using TeX live 2022 installed in `/usr/local/texlive/2022`, which is the default directory.

Thanks for any tips.

Comment: does it really say `<blank>` ? This sounds as if something in the preferences is wrong.

Comment: well no, that's just name of the file I tried to hide :) sorry for the confusion

Comment: To add the path to `pdflatex`, did you modify the `/etc/environment` file or just your `.profile` file?

Answer (score 0):

So, it was just me being stupid,  per @Paul Gaborit's suggestion. I thought that adding the pdflatex to `.profile` file would not be the best idea. Hence, adding it the the `etc/environment` helped solve the issue after restarting the PC. Thank you!